# Laravel Query with Sum of value from child table if value column in parent table greater than sum of value in child

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

I am trying to query for rows from transaction table where the amount is less than sum of allocations against that transaction row in allocations table. This works halfway. It is giving me all transaction queries with an additional field of "allocated_amount".

```
$all_transactions = Transaction::
    withCount([
        'allocations AS amount_allocated' => function ($query) {
            $query->select(
                DB::raw("CAST(SUM(amount) AS INTEGER)"
            ));
        }
    ])
    ->where('contact_type','supplier')
    ->where('contact_id',$ehead->supplier_id)
    ->get()->toArray();
```

Result

```
 0 => array:12 [▼
    "id" => 4
    "amount" => 10000
    "created_by" => 1
    "amount_allocated" => 7500
  ]
  1 => array:12 [▼
    "id" => 5
    "amount" => 10000
    "created_by" => 1
    "amount_allocated" => 10000
  ]
```

But I don't want the second result to come up because amount = amount allocated. How to fix this query?

Tried using:

```
->where('amount','>','allocated_amount')
```

but maybe because it is additionally added filed, throws an error saying allocated field does not exist. I need it within the query, not as a separate addition.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in this case you can simply use [map()](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-map)

```
$all_transactions = collect($all_transactions)->map(function ($row) {
    if ($row['amount'] > $row['amount_allocated']) {
        return $row;
    }
})->filter()->toArray();  // filter() to remove null values
```

Comment: This works. Is there a way we could do directly on the query itself?

Comment: Probably `->having('amount','>','allocated_amount')`

Comment: returns nothing. Empty array

Comment: Then I guess use collection map() instead. Laravel Collection is meant for such calculation after querying results.